# Using a string to build Query DSL for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Meteor (so Javascript, Node, NPM, etc) and would like to provide a simple text input for users to search via Elasticsearch. I would like to be able to use modifiers on the text like + and "" and search for a specific field. I'm looking for something that can convert a plain text input into Elasticsearch Query DSL.

These would be some example queries:

This query would mean that the keyword "tatooine" must exist:

```
stormtrooper +tatooine
```

This would mean that "death star" should be one keyword:

```
stormtrooper "death star"
```

This would search for the keyword "bloopers" only in the category field:

```
stormtrooper category=bloopers
```

Is there a library that can do this? Can a generic solution exist or is this why I can't find any existing answers to this?

Answer (score 1):

[`simple_query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) would support your query syntax out of the box, except for `category=bloopers` which should be `category:bloopers` instead, but otherwise it should work:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "stormtrooper category:bloopers"
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "stormtrooper +tatooine"
    }
  }
}'
```

You can also send the query in the [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) directly like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/_search?q=stormtrooper%20%22death%20star%22"
```